# Memory efficient way of logging to a database BLOB column long running php script

Tags: php, mysql

I am logging to a database table after building a large string as a BLOB. The problem I think that is happening is the string is becoming very large as the long runs causing memory issues on the php script. I can write the string to a file but I will still have to load it into memory to log to mysql.

Is there any way to do this without causing memory issues on web server?

Example

```
$this->log("1");
$this->log("2");
$this->log("3");
$this->log("4");
....
function log($msg)
{
  $this->log.=$msg;
}

function save_log()
{
      insert into log ('msg') VALUES ($this->log)
}
```

Comment: BY "BLOG" you mean "BLOB"?

Comment: Please define _very large_

Comment: Please also define _memory issues_

Comment: I meant BLOB. I am running the script that logs a new line every 2 seconds. It has been running for 12 hours and the memory usage is increasing from the string getting large (That is my guess)

Comment: Simple suggestion: Count the number of messages sent and then write to log (and clear `$this->log`) every X logged messages

Comment: If you are getting a new log line every 2 seconds, why aren't you writing each line individually and then clearing the temp storage variable?

Comment: _new line every 2 seconds.It has been running for 12 hours_ `= 21,600` lines in your in memory string. Which of course is TOTALLY USELESS to you until the script terminates and you write it to the database. Sounds like this was not well thought through

Comment: Why not log each string item directly to the database. You can do append in mysql.

Comment: @Henry What is the best way to append in mysql so I don't have to save to a big string. The column that holds the data in a blob. Will this have any performance issues as the blob grows?

Comment: I don't get what I did wrong in asking my question; I ended up getting the answer that I was looking for but why I did I get so many downvotes. It was a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append to a blob, of course you need to have the right ID fort the blob or all blobs are appended.

```
update log set msg = concat(msg, "test to append");
```

On the other hand I would not create such a big blob i cant read out or search through.
I would create a log table which hold the log id and create date and updated date. then create a database with of the individual log items and give them a link to the log id.

This will make the logs easily to search through.

```
log_id  log_name  log_create   log_update
1       userlog   2018-31-12   2018-31-12 19:37

item_id   log_id item_create        item_text
1         1      2018-31-12 19:37   the text of the log event
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are accumulating a very large string in memory, waiting to be written to database at the end of the php process. Memory overconsumption comes for your php var which is storing the string, not from database.

It would be much better to periodically write data to database, and reinitialize the php var to free process memory.

In mysql, you can append to a `BLOB` using the `CONCAT function :`

```
UPDATE log SET msg = CONCAT(msg, ?);
```

Where the question mark is the value of the php var.

Comment: Thanks this is what I ending up doing